What is blender tools name?
What is the name of tools in the below of image, I cant find it in any blender version. I use blender version 3.6, 4.0 and 4.2


It is a tool for Grease Pencil objects in Edit Mode. The upper icon is the Extrude tool, the icon below is the Interpolate tool. But if you have no idea where to find them and what they are for, where have you seen them and why do you need them?


Oh i see, I have learn poly modeling for right now, thats image I seen on the tutorial short on youtube but I forgot the name of channel. I want to improve my forkflow for sculpting and poly modeling for minimize perfomance my low budget of my PC. Thank you sir for the answer.

@adityanugraha You're welcome. Please read: What should I do when someone answers my question?.
